# React-router issues using static-render-webpack-plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I just started working with React last week, and I'm having trouble following [a tutorial](http://www.qimingweng.com/writing/webpack-static-render) for the [static-render-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/qimingweng/static-render-webpack-plugin).

I've put the code [online at GitHub](https://github.com/jackiejohnston/test-static-react) if you want to take a closer look.

After following the tutorial and making a couple of changes (I added babel-core, I changed the js loader to babel-loader and the entry point url needed a small correction), when I try to run `webpack -p` to generate the static files I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./src/entry.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: .../src/entry.js: Unexpected token (10:2)
   8 |
   9 | const routes = (
> 10 |   <Route path="/" handler={RootPage}>
     |   ^
```

I think it might have something to do with [the changes made with the latest version of react-router](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/832c42946c874fe56ffde0066b1088054311cb98/CHANGES.md). I'm using the latest version, but the syntax for the tutorial looks like it might have been written prior to v.1.0. For example, I think the part of the tutorial that says to add this to the `src/entry.js` file:

```
if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
  Router.run(routes, path, (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root/>, document);
  });
}
```

probably needs to be rewritten to something like this (but I'm not sure if this is quite right):

```
if (typeof document != 'undefined') {
  ReactDOM.render(routes, document);
}
```

There's obviously more going on though since I get the same error message when I try that rewritten snippet then run `webpack-dev-server` -- which is the only time it should hit that code. (Yes, I added `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';` to the top of the page and `"react-dom": "^0.14.7",` to the `package.json`.)

I am sure this part (also on `src/entry.js`) needs to be rewritten to match the latest `react-router` too but I'm not sure how:

```
export default function(path, props, callback) {
  Router.run(routes, path, (Root) => {
    const html = React.renderToString(<Root/>);
    callback('<!doctype html>' + html);
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or hints you can give.

Comment: I'm running into similar issues. It's been a few weeks since you posted this. Any luck?! 

Comment: @Ivanoats Sorry, I wasn't able to get it working. I think maybe trying the tutorial using "react-router": "1.0.3" instead of the 2.0 version might be a starting point, but without knowing versions for all dependencies there's a lot of guesswork involved. I really wish the plugin linked to a working demo and repo. I've been looking into http://www.metalsmith.io/ as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks - yes, on both points. The repo should have a working example beyond the tests, and, Metalsmith is my backup, too.

Comment: @Ivanoats if you are still looking for an alternative solution, this looks like a winner: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby

Answer (score 0):

Your code is breaking because Webpack doesn't know how to transpile the JSX to ES5. You've specified `babel-loader` as your loader for JS files in your webpack config, but unfortunately Babel 6 does not do anything out of the box, you need to include "plugins" that contain the rules for compiling different syntaxes down to ES5. In this case, you'll want the `es2015` preset to support all ES6 syntax, and the `react` preset to support JSX. You're also missing the `extract-text-webpack-plugin` you are trying to import into your webpack config. Snag these through NPM:

```
npm i -D babel-preset-2015 babel-preset-react extract-text-webpack-plugin
```

Then, add the presets to your webpack.config.js file in the loaders section for js/jsx files:

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                         
  test: /\.(js|jsx)?$/,                                                                                                                                                                                   
  loader: 'babel',                                                                                                                                                                            
  exclude: /node_modules/,                                                                                                                                                                           
  query: {                                                                                                                                                                                           
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']                                                                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

I forked your repo and made these changes and was able to get a bit further through the compilation process. It seems like there are module dependencies specific to your project you'll still need to resolve.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I appreciate the explanation. I've made the changes, and no longer get the same error message! It's an improvement. I now have to figure out why it says `ERROR in NotFoundRoute is not defined`. I tried removing the 404 page entirely, but then got a series of `ERROR in render is not a function` messages. After some Googling, I think I might be back to the upgrade issue with React and react-router.

Comment: Is it all pushed up to the repo? I'd be happy to take a look at the code later.

Comment: Yes, it's there. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JackieJohnston The NotFoundRoute error is most likely because you are using a newer version of react-router. NotFoundRoute is no longer a valid path. Instead, use <Route path="*"/> as the last route. This route "catches" everything because of the star, and is basically the new NotFoundRoute.

Comment: @Qiming Thanks, that did get rid of that error message. Now it's complaining that "ERROR in render is not a function". It spits out 4 of these errors in a row, no doubt one for each of the pages it's trying to render.

Comment: @JackieJohnston it's a bit too onerous to transform the tutorial into the react-router 1.0/2.0 syntax. Can you try using react-router 0.13 and see if that solves most of the problems, just as a starting point?

Comment: Another thing that was noticed in the past was that you have to export the global function module as `module.exports`, and not `export default`. I forget who raised the issue but if I find it I'll link you to it.